# Enabling HTTPS on all Synology ports

Tags: https, synology

I’m attempting to set up external access for a couple services on my Synology DiskStation. I have a cert created from LetEncrypt (using the DSM’s GUI to do so) and I can access `https://mysynology.synology.me:5001` just fine but any of my other externally accessible ports are only accessible via HTTP. Otherwise they complain:

> “This site can’t provide a secure connection.”

I’m guessing there’s a config error somewhere that I’m missing but I haven't found any information in any guides.

Comment: Is the cert a wildcard certificate for a hostname? What is the hostname associated with the cert.

Comment: So far as I know it's not a wildcard cert. Hostname is a Synology.me name, similar to th example but without a port specified. For some reason I need to specify a port when accessing the URL. All ports work but only the 5001 port works over HTTPS.

Comment: You have forwarded the port to your device on your router?  Additionally, you have gone into Synology and enabled any external access options that might exist?

Comment: Yes. As I said, the ports are accessible, just over HTTP but not HTTPS.

Comment: Did you follow [these instructions](https://www.synology.com/en-us/knowledgebase/DSM/tutorial/Network/How_to_enable_HTTPS_and_create_a_certificate_signing_request_on_your_Synology_NAS) from Synology themselves?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Not from there specifically but that's the process I used. I didn't enter a wildcard value.

Comment: For the record, I haven't manually configured anything on my router. While setting up EZ-Internet it configured that for me (in theory). I'm using a Ubiquiti USG.